# Python - google content api and unicode

Tags: python, unicode, google-content-api

I've searched through so many pages to try and help myself that I'm now more confused on python2 and unicode than I was before I started.

What I'm trying to achieve:

Using the google content api v2 for python, I've written an implementation that will take products from our database and post them to Google.

This works fine until I get to some products which have unicode characters in them.

An example and the errors returned from google/python are:

```
D' Addario EXP11 Coated Bronze Acoustic Guitar Strings, 12-53 
Fender Stop Dreaming, Start Playing™ Affinity P Bass® With Rumble™ 15 

ERROR'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 1: invalid start byte
ERROR'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 35: invalid start byte
```

I know its the ' ® ™  characters but I can't work out the .encode / .decode etc. aspect of it.

So, can anyone tell me how I can take these product names with special characters in them so that I can post them to Google?

== update ==
I'm getting the product names from a MySQL db. The table is set to use UTF-8 as the encoding.

Comment: Also make sure that you are saving your file as UTF-8 and not some other encoding.

Comment: do you mean by putting # coding=utf-8 at the top of the file ?

Comment: No, as in configuring your editor to save as UTF-8.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo . thanks for the info, but i'm getting these product names directly from MySQL , using UTF-8 as the DB encoding type. How will my editor help me ?

Comment: It won't; I thought you were hardcoding them. Disregard what I said.

Comment: they're *not* in UTF-8 in mysql then... sounds fishy.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
u'Addario EXP11 Coated Bronze Acoustic Guitar Strings, 12-53 
Fender Stop Dreaming, Start Playing™ Affinity P Bass® With Rumble™ 15'
```

or

```
unicode('Addario EXP11 Coated Bronze Acoustic Guitar Strings, 12-53 
Fender Stop Dreaming, Start Playing™ Affinity P Bass® With Rumble™ 15')
```

But that aside. Unicode support in Python 2 is a pain in the ass a lot of times. I recommend trying Python 3 where unicode is standard.

Comment: I tried the unicode() approach and that didn't seem to work, I seem to remember getting other errors.

Comment: I'll try and dig out the issues when I post via the unicode() method, I was attempting to convert it to python3 as well!

Comment: >>> mytext = unicode('Fender Stop Dreaming, Start Playing™ Affinity P Bass® With Rumble™ 15')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 35: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 is, the answer :) (now google support it with their sdk)